# how to use SAS enterprise guide(8.3) to connect to SFTP server to get a file

Tags: sas, etl, sftp

recently,I am using SAS enterprise guide to setup an ETL flow to move data from a file in SFTP server to a relational database.
SAS enterprise guide is installed as a client in a laptop; here, no SAS server involved.
In this laptop, I can use WinScp to connect to SFTP server with Key file.
I wonder how to setup SAS enterprise guide so that it can connect to SFTP server to get a file. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl SAS Enterprise Guide is a programmer's tool (it's like Eclipse for SAS, roughly, with some additional ETL stuff).

Comment: I am not sure what you are proposing.  Are you asking how to link to a file that you only access via SFTP from a remote server as part of your process flow in Enterprise Guide?  What are you planning to DO with the file?  If you want to use it with SAS code then you are probably going to want to allow the SAS server where your SAS code is running to connect to the SFTP server instead of trying to have your PC or EG connect.

Comment: @Tom It sounds like there is no SAS server, just local EG.

Comment: What can you do with EG without access to SAS?  Or do you mean EG is connecting to SAS running on the same machine instead of a "server".

Comment: The latter, from what I read, but it definitely would be helpful to have that more explicitly clarified.  That's how I used EG for my first ~5 years using it - we had local SAS installs, and I preferred to use EG as my IDE than the base SAS editor, as I suspect many programmers with non-SAS backgrounds might.  EG comes default with workstation SAS installs, and has since nearly its inception I believe.

Comment: Fred Wu - please do clarify that, if you're using EG but there is no SAS license whatsoever, this is a very different question (and one with a negative answer).

Comment: "Are you asking how to link to a file that you only access via SFTP from a remote server as part of your process flow in Enterprise Guide?"  Yes, only access via SFTP from a remote server as part of my process flow in Enterprise Guide.

Comment: " It sounds like there is no SAS server, just local EG."   Yes, Joe's comment is right

Comment: @joe, I have SAS license of course. Here SAS EG is regards as ETL tool for the data flow. if your solution need SAS server involved , that is ok.

Comment: For the most part, EG isn't really an ETL tool - SAS is the ETL, EG is just a programming environment.  SAS can do ETL fine.  There is a full featured SAS ETL tool (Data Integration Studio, or Data Management Studio), but that requires a server and a lot more expensive license.  But really, just normal SAS programs are fine for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a SAS Server, but using it in "local server" mode, then you're just asking a normal SAS question, really.  There's no  SFTP task in EG.

Your best bet is to use the `FILENAME SFTP` route; [this SAS forum thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Move-files-between-server-using-SFTP/td-p/350673) shows an example.  Basically, you have

```
filename sftp 'file.csv' options "some options based on your locale" cd "directory" host="host" user="user"
```

More or less... see [Filename statement SFTP access method](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsglobal/p0xln1fiwsr340n1xxf4mkmfxp6f.htm) for more details.

Then you can read in the file from there using whatever import task you want.

Comment: Joe, thanks for your response! let me have some time to digest and test in my office environment via VPN  soon. Will update you the result. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the method of "filename sftp" statement. there are two problems:  1. my SAS enterprise guide is installed in my laptop, while SAS server is in another machine; and I can use winscp client to connect to SFTP server from my laptop, but from SAS server it cannot connect to SFTP server.

Comment: 2. even I copy .ppk file into my SAS server, the following command still not success:  filename file1 sftp "11111.csv"  cd='c:\"  options='-i c:\kkkk.ppk' host=10.1.2.33 user='username"